# Converting JSON string to NSDate occurs an error

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Here is a json string value I receive need to convert to NSDate:

> 2017-04-08T13:51:00.000+03:00

And here is I convert to NSDate:

```
+ (NSDate *)stringDateToDate:(NSString *)aStringDate
{
    NSDate *date = nil;

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSS"];

    date = [dateFormat dateFromString:aStringDate];
    NSLog(@"nsdate: %@", date);

    return date;
}
```

As result it logs:

> nsdate: (null)

Seems that date format is incorrect. How to fix that issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following date formatter string

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"
```

which uses `ZZZZZ` for the timezone / zone / time offset - e.g. +03:00
`SSS` for the fractional seconds - e.g. 123
and most importantly uses `.` between the seconds and its fractions instead of `:`

> *Thanks to rmaddy for correcting the number of `S` and  `Z` to meet the exact required input*

Note that you can get away with using `SZ` instead of `SSSZZZZZ` because the parser is smart enough to parse it anyway. If you want to create a string from a date however you need the above date formatter string.

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SZ"
```

[image]

> More details on date formatter strings can be found in the unicode section for
>   [`Date Format Patterns`](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: @luk2302 technically it is a time offset from UTC, not time zone.

Comment: @BryanHadlock yes, technically in this case you are probably right, in general it is a key for just `zone`, I will correct that. In some cases there is an actual timezone indicator present as well, not in this case however.

Comment: You need `SSS`, mot `SSSS`. And a timezone in the format `+00:00` requires `ZZZZZ`, not ``ZZZ``.

Comment: @rmaddy Hmmmm you may actually be right, but I am wondering why my code works then. Is it possible that the number of `Z` and `S` is more important for the output than it is for the input?

Comment: It may work with `SZ` because the parser is smart enough to deal with various formats on input. But I doubt it works with `SSSSZZZ` on input (or output) because those specify specific formats.

Comment: @rmaddy I changed the answer to incorporate that feedback.

Comment: @luk2302 One uppercase handles standard date-time offset, the rest is probably ignored. Lowercase is for time zones. MST, EDT etc. Offset deals with what time it was when the value was set against UTC which stays the same without daylight savings time. Uppercase Z stand for Zulu.

Comment: @luk2302 Time zones can be tricky since some countries don't follow the standards, so it is easier to use offsets from UTC

Answer (score -1):

Z at the end for the time offset

```
+ (NSDate *)stringDateToDate:(NSString *)aStringDate
{
   NSDate *date = nil;

   NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSSZ"];

   date = [dateFormat dateFromString:aStringDate];
   NSLog(@"nsdate: %@", date);

   return date;
}
```

Comment: And still that would not work because you have a : instead of . between the seconds and its fractions.

Comment: Darn it, did not see that.